# Different CLI InputEncoding between Console and VS Code console

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

There is a different InputEncoding used by VS Code PowerShell console vs. the console outside of VS Code. What are the differences and/or pitfalls that might occur because of this?

```
PS C:\Users\lit> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()
7.2.1

PS C:\Users\lit> $Host

Name             : Visual Studio Code Host
Version          : 2021.11.1
InstanceId       : fb65bead-b049-4ac8-befd-54df023771fd
UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
CurrentCulture   : en-US
CurrentUICulture : en-US
PrivateData      : 
DebuggerEnabled  : True
IsRunspacePushed : False
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace

PS C:\Users\lit> [console]::InputEncoding

Preamble          : 
BodyName          : utf-8
EncodingName      : Unicode (UTF-8)
HeaderName        : utf-8
WebName           : utf-8
WindowsCodePage   : 1200
IsBrowserDisplay  : True
IsBrowserSave     : True
IsMailNewsDisplay : True
IsMailNewsSave    : True
IsSingleByte      : False
EncoderFallback   : System.Text.EncoderReplacementFallback
DecoderFallback   : System.Text.DecoderReplacementFallback
IsReadOnly        : False
CodePage          : 65001
```

However, from a command console outside of VS Code:

```
PS C:\src\t> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()
7.2.1

PS C:\src\t> $host

Name             : ConsoleHost
Version          : 7.2.1
InstanceId       : 41168572-6825-4b84-897a-77432d0a20a3
UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
CurrentCulture   : en-US
CurrentUICulture : en-US
PrivateData      : Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost+ConsoleColorProxy
DebuggerEnabled  : True
IsRunspacePushed : False
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace

PS C:\src\t> [console]::InputEncoding

IsSingleByte      : True
EncodingName      : OEM United States
WebName           : ibm437
HeaderName        : ibm437
BodyName          : ibm437
Preamble          :
WindowsCodePage   :
IsBrowserDisplay  :
IsBrowserSave     :
IsMailNewsDisplay :
IsMailNewsSave    :
EncoderFallback   : System.Text.InternalEncoderBestFitFallback
DecoderFallback   : System.Text.InternalDecoderBestFitFallback
IsReadOnly        : True
CodePage          : 437
```

Comment: I think this might give you a hint https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/15339544. On Windows OEM and ANSI seem to be the default Encoding as opposed to Linux in my case (UTF-8). VSCode probably does something like: `$OutputEncoding = [Console]::InputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8` each time it starts.

Comment: VS Code has a separate `$Profile`, so make sure you set `utf8` in both. -- See `$profile | select *` to see the locations for the current terminal.  -- By that I mean the `Integrated Terminal`. It doesn't run off the same assembly as the external system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of VSCode 1.63 and the PowerShell extension v2021.12.0, the behavior is as follows:

- **VSCode's *integrated terminal* behaves like regular console windows** with respect to character encoding.

  - This means that the **system's active *OEM code page*** (e.g., [`437`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code%20page%20437) on US-English systems) is in effect by default, as configured in the system locale (language for non-Unicode programs), and as reflected in the output from `chcp.com`.
  - Note that recent versions of Windows 10 have a still-in-beta feature that allows you to set both the OEM and the ANSI code pages to `65001`, i.e. to switch to UTF-8 *system-wide*, although that has far-reaching consequences - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375).
- The **PowerShell extension** for VSCode - which comes with its a *customized* PowerShell terminal called the ***PowerShell Integrated Console*** - **uses its own settings**:

  - It **sets `[Console]::OutputEncoding` to UTF-8** (code page `65001`), so that *output from external programs is decoded as UTF-8 text*. This is arguably the better choice for modern CLIs, such as `node.exe`, but - as with the default code page - you may have to *situationally* change `[Console]::OutputEncoding` (temporarily) to match a given program's (nonstandard) character encoding.
  - Curiously, it doesn't *also* set `[Console]::InputEncoding` to UTF-8, though in practice that setting only matters if you pipe input to PowerShell *from the outside*. (However, a side effect of not changing this setting is that `chcp.com` still reports the OEM code page, even though the *output* code page has in effect been changed to `65001` via `[Console]::OutputEncoding`).

---

Your findings imply that the **your integrated terminal settings have been *customized***, such as with:

```
$OutputEncoding = [Console]::InputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()
```

as [Santiago](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) points out, which is how you can **make a PowerShell console fully UTF-8-aware.**

As for *where* this customization may be applied: Probably in your VSCode-specific [profile file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles), as reflected in `$PROFILE`, as [ninMonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341744/ninmonkey) points out.